# Angularjs and filters returning JS error

Tags: angularjs

I am having problems getting the angular seed framework working for filters, it is fine for services and directives but returns a "FilterProvider" error when I wire up a filter.

I really cant see where i am going wrong? i have set up a [JSFiddle here ->](http://jsfiddle.net/method7/33gmv6xk/)

```
<div ng:app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items  | {filter : notZero}">
   <strong>{{item.title}}</strong> {{item.qty}}
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

with my controllers and filter like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'myApp.controllers',
  'myApp.filters'
]);

angular.module('myApp.filters', [])
  .filter('notZero', function() {
     return function( items, condition) {
      console.log( items, condition);

    };
  })

angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [  
   {  
      "title":"40cm",
      "qty":3
   },
   {  
      "title":"55cm",
      "qty":2
   },
   {  
      "title":"60cm",
      "qty":0
   },
   {  
      "title":"70cm",
      "qty":4
   }
];
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you invoke a custom filter:

```
<div ng:app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | notZero">
   <strong>{{item.title}}</strong> {{item.qty}}
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7jb5tru/)

Comment: ahh Wawy I was so close thanks you :-) i notice the condition is undefined I guess you simply add notZero: 'myCondition'